# Adding a dynamic directive inside another directive template in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

I want to add dynamic directive inside another directive tempalte.
As you see I want to add another directive inside a directive template
How do add those dynamic directive there

Please help

```
return {
restrict: 'AE',
require :'^awkGrid',
templateUrl: 'views/shutter.html',
link : function(scope, element, attr, controllerInstance){

    //Set the header
    scope.items = [];
    angular.forEach(scope.rowData, function(value, key) {

        var obj = {
            key : key,
            value : value
        };


        template = <country name="'+value.country+'" id="'+key+'"></country>;
        scope.items.push(template);
    });
};
//Inside shutter.html file
 <div data-ng-repeat="item in items" class="ag-row action-row"
 ng-class-odd="'ag-row-even'"
 ng-class-even="'ag-row-odd'"
 ng-class="{'ag-row-selected':$index == selectedRow}"
 ng-click="setClickedRow($index,$event)">
<div class="ag-cell">
            {{item}} //Not working ,Prinitng the string
    <country name="india" id="-1"></country> //Working
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have to recompile your directive. Add folowing code at the end of link function:

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

Answer is in [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

Of course, you have to add service `$compile` to your directive as a dependency.

Comment: not working it is still showing 
<country name="india" id="-1"></country> as string

Comment: Can you put your solution to jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible

Comment: As you can see
<country name="india" id="-1"></country> this tag is working
but when I attach it to a scope
then it is not compiling

Comment: Maybe try to make a join on `scope.items.join('')`, then append it to directive content and then try to recompile.

Comment: var link = function(scope, elem, attrs){
        scope.country = '<country name="india"></country>';
        $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
    }

this also not working

in html 

{{country}}

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically switch out the entire template of a directive you have to set the element's html to the desired new template and then pass the element's contents into `$compile` to bind it with the `$scope`.

`element.html('<h1>Dynamic Content</h1>').show();`

`$compile(element.contents())($scope);`

This should all be defined in the `link` function of the directive in question.